# how can i create project with CLI in linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, command-line-interface

i have already one runnig project in vue js with installed node js ,now i want to create new project with CLI ,so is it required to install a new node js version ??

Comment: What exactly is a project with CLI for you? *Every* program can be run on the command line on Linux! Every running program has been started by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (and your shell is doing an `execve` after a [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to run every program). You should read more about Linux programming, e.g. read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Answer (score 1):

> so is it required to install a new node js version

No. For what? Just type

```
node script.js
```

or

```
nodejs script.js
```

in terminal.

Comment: You want project with CLI (command line interface), right? You can just run your script. You can run few nodejs servers in one host with different projects. You can use containers like docker, if you want, and run projects inside it.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution of my question may it help someone other..
follow the step and your project will execute successfully..
1)create your project folder any where
2)go to that folder using cd command
3)enter this command : sudo npm install --global vue-cli
4)enter this command : sudo vue init webpack ex_cli
5)cd project folder name
6)npm install
7)npm run dev

i had create successfully my project as this way..

Now it successfully run your project like..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhTlu.png)